# loop through list of elements and read values via querystring

Tags: jquery

I am assigning values to an unordered list via jquery selectList

After selecting options from the selectList the unordered list looks like this

```
<ul id="myList">
<li id="3">Cat</li>
<li id="7">Dog</li>
<li id="12">Fish</li>
</ul>
```

This needs to be done client side via jquery.

What is the best approach to read these values in via querystring in the code behind?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean reading text content of `li` elements?

Comment: `$('#myList li').each(function(){ alert($(this).text()) })`

Comment: why did you flagged it in C#?

Comment: Hi Yes I need to read in the text and ID of each li element and then somehow pass this to a hidden field array and then read in via querystring , ie    var _values = Request.QueryString["itemsList"];

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hidden `<select multiple="multiple">` with all the options as `option` items. And set all of them to `selected="selected"`.

That way, all your values get serialized in the query string as `a=10&b=12...` and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer could you give a small example please?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by looping through the list and appending each value to a variable then assigning the variable to a hidden field.  Works fine.